# SQL query output

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I try this sql query

```
Select 
    tblRV.ID as ID, tblRV.Owner, tblRV.Regno,
    (Select Count(*) as total 
     from tblvv 
     where MID = tblRV.ID and Name <> '') as total,
    tblRV.MA, tblRV.MS 
from 
    tblReg 
inner join 
    tblRV On tblReg.RID = tblRV.RID
where  
    tblReg.StartDate >= '2016-06-01 00:00:00' and
    tblReg.EndDate <= '2016-06-08 23:59:59' and 
    tblReg.Region = 'UK' 
order by 
    tblRV.Owner
```

This query returns 24 rows. So when I created my procedure and execute it like this

```
grid_data 'UK' ,'2016-06-01 00:00:00', '2016-06-08 23:59:59'
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[grid_data]
    @region varchar(50),
    @fromdate datetime,
    @todate datetime
AS
    SELECT
        tblRV.ID as ID, tblRV.Owner, tblRV.Regno,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
         FROM tblvv 
         WHERE MID = tblRV.ID and Name <> '') AS total,
        tblRV.MA, tblRV.MS 
    FROM
        tblReg 
    INNER JOIN 
        tblRV ON tblReg.RID = tblRV.RID
    ORDER BY
       tblRV.Owner
```

This procedure returns 24913 records.

Comment: both query are identitcal. It should return same no of rows

Comment: I assume this is not your real sp code - because you are not using arguments here.

Comment: And how many rows will return first query, if you change `UK` to `Faisalabad`?

Comment: Ivan is right. You are calling variables you are not using. Check the first query again,  highlight the script, copy into your usp and run again. If your variables are meant to be used, try a use case you can verify the results from.

Comment: @gofr1 check update

Comment: @IvanStarostin so how i solve this

Comment: @IvanStarostin this is real sp code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try amending your SP to include a `WHERE` clause based on your parameters - like so:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[grid_data]
@region varchar(50),
@fromdate datetime,
@todate datetime
as
Select tblRV.ID as ID, tblRV.Owner, tblRV.Regno,
       (Select Count(*) as total from tblvv WHERE MID = tblRV.ID and Name <> '')
                as total,tblRV.MA, tblRV.MS 
from tblReg inner join tblRV On tblReg.RID = tblRV.RID
WHERE tblReg.StartDate >= @fromdate AND tblReg.EndDate <= @todate 
and tblReg.Region = @region
order by tblRV.Owner
```

Answer (score 0):

No `WHERE` clause in the stored procedure